# Figuring out what's wrong with the sentence

Tags: meaning, punctuation, commas, ambiguity

I took a quiz given in the BBC magazine. it had the following sentence.

> The Queen arrived at the castle with the King by her side, in a dress
>   adorned with hand-sewn embroidered dragons.

please explain what is technically wrong with the above sentence.

Comment: Nothing, if it was the King who was in the dress.

Comment: Needs a comma after _castle_ to avoid the King becoming a _queen_.

Comment: :-) funny, and right. I guess I have to pay attention to details.

Comment: The comma doesn't save it. It's still ambiguous; to make it unambiguous (it's not ungrammatical, hence not "bad", either way), you have to move the phrase describing the queen's dress to a position following _queen_. As long as _king_ is between _queen_ and _dress_, the king in the dress is still a valid sense, and would be automatically chosen by a translation program, since they don't depend much on punctuation.

Comment: P.S. Don't trust the BBC when it comes to language (or science). They have a terrible record.

Comment: will it not help if a comma is put after "arrived"?

Comment: I mean, come off it. Who is seriously going to think that Prince Philip was wearing a richly embroidered dress. :)) (Before anyone says anything, I know he's not the king. But I can imagine him being a secret cross dresser, the tiaras, the gowns, the flashy handbags (purses)...)

Comment: I agree with the last comment and a slight rearrangement of words as follows. "The Queen arrived at the castle in a dress adorned with hand-sewn embroidered dragons, with the King by her side".

Answer (score 1):

There should be a comma after "Castle" which clearly seperates the phrase "with the King by her side". The comma after "by her side" clearly indicates that it is the Queen that is wearing the 'hand-sewn' dress.

Comment: No. Putting in the comma still does not solve the problem. The prepositional phrase should be moved next to the noun group it is modifying:

The Queen, in a dress adorned with hand-sewn embroidered dragons, arrived at the castle with the King by her side.